# File attribute constants in Windows C programming

Tags: windows, file, winapi, attributes, hidden

I have a file called `myhj.txt` which I hid with using this command from cmd `attrib +h +s +r myhj.txt`. Now I can't open the file with standart `fopen()` function in C, so I have decided to use `GetFileAttributes()` function which *does not* return an error. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944(VS.85).aspx), when the function succeeds the return value is [File Attribute Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117(v=vs.85).aspx)

I don't know how to get their values as the program crushes when it tries to run `printf()` down below. Also would it work stable when the file is hidden? How do I access a hidden file with all of its values?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *log;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  if(GetFileAttributes("myhj.txt") == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES){
    printf("invalid get last error %d", GetLastError());
  }else{
    printf("%s", FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY);
  }

}
```

Comment: This question illustrates an abundant lack of insight into even the basics, like `printf` format specifiers or bit flags. An answer is unlikely to be useful to future visitors.

Comment: I would agree, it's not `printf()` I just had problems understanding the usage of the function. I will delete it soon @IInspectable

Comment: then I have a question prof, how do I write data to a hidden file?? @IInspectable `fopen()` with `a+` then `fprintf()` doesn't work on hidden files.

Comment: Why do you insist, that opening a hidden file were any different from opening any other file? The *hidden* attribute is a hint for tools, whether or not to display a file **to the user**. It has no impact on actual file operations. This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), specifically, you are trying to open the file for **writing**, when you have marked it read-only.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a classic example of the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). It is unlikely to be useful to future visitors.

Comment: @IInspectable okay, I have checked the commands and I am setting it to read file only, It was my mistake, would fopen return well if i remove it??

Comment: I am very sorry @IInspectable

Comment: If it takes you less than a minute to try, why not simply try it?

Comment: @IInspectable I am in a class :)) I guess this really was an XY problem.

Answer (score 5):

It crashes because `%s` expects a null-terminated string but the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_*` constants are integers instead, so it ends up trying to read a string from an invalid memory address. Use `%d` instead:

```
printf("%d", FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY);
```

`GetFileAttributes()` returns a `DWORD`, which is an `unsigned int`, so use `%u` for it:

```
DWORD att = GetFileAttributes("myhj.txt");
if (att == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) {
    printf("invalid get last error %d", GetLastError());
}
else {
    printf("%u", att);
}
```

To check for specific values, test each bit separately using the bitwise AND operator (`&`):

```
DWORD att = GetFileAttributes("file.ext");
if (att == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) {
  printf("error!\n");
}
else
{
  if (att & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) printf("directory\n");
  if (att & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN) printf("hidden\n");
  ...
}
```

If you set the read-only attribute on a file, you cannot perform destructive operations on it...

Comment: You read data from a hidden file the same way you read data from any other file. That question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Use `CreateFile` and ask for `GENERIC_READ` access. Don't ask for `DELETE` and/or `*WRITE*` if the file might be read-only.

Comment: @IInspectable, it's more reasonable to ask how to overwrite a hidden file. That one is a bit special. `CreateFile` requires the file to remain hidden with a `CREATE_ALWAYS` disposition, i.e. `dwFlagsAndAttributes` needs to have `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN`.

Comment: @eryksun: To my knowledge, `fopen` takes care of that. The OP was moving away from `fopen`, because they didn't understand the consequences with respect to writing to a file after making it read-only.

Comment: @IInspectable, `fopen` in "w" mode fails for hidden or system files because of the create-always disposition. One either has to clear the hidden or system flag or delete the file. `fopen` with "a" or "a+" mode isn't a problem with hidden or system files, since it uses an open-always disposition -- but append mode fails for read-only files since the CRT requests generic write access.

Comment: @eryksun: The OP is [apparently using `"a+"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46340370/file-attribute-constants-in-windows-c-programming#comment79641972_46340370), and I was commenting on that scenario. No matter how you slice it, this is an XY Problem, unlikely to be useful to future readers.

Comment: @IInspectable after realizing my mistake, I have recently came to realize "w" does not work,

Comment: how do I write over a file? I was thinking of removing. the hidden attr and run the function and add the attrib back again, is there a better way? @eryksun

Comment: @turmuka, staying within the CRT, you can open `f = fopen("file.ext", "r+")` and immediately truncate it via `_chsize(_fileno(f), 0)`. Or start with a low I/O file descriptor `fd = _open("file.ext", _O_WRONLY | _O_TRUNC)` and open a stream `f = _fdopen(fd, "w")`.

Comment: what about removing the hidden attribute and ten doing `"w"` and then giving it the hidden attribute right back again. I am considering running command with `system()` function doing `attrib -h` @eryksun

Comment: @turmuka, I prefer the simplicity of a single `_open` call that doesn't require modifying the file attributes, or even dropping down to `hFile = CreateFile(...)` followed by `fd = _open_osfhandle(hFile, _O_TEXT)`. Of course calling `GetFileAttributes` and `SetFileAttributes` will also work, or calling `_spawnl` to run attrib.exe (no need for `system` here; this isn't a shell command).

Comment: @eryksun since I could get reactions asking this question since it was already asked, I decided to ask you, How can I stop console window appearing in the screen when I run a program. I have tried ShowWindow and FreeConsole() but in both of them I see the console for like a second.

Comment: If you don't want to create a console program then you must change your linker settings and switch from main() to [WinMain()](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/simple_window.html).

Comment: @turmuka, it's a two-part problem. There's a compile-time linker flag in the PE header that sets the process subsystem. This affects what the loader links to and executes at startup. The minimum is an NT native process, which only loads ntdll.dll. Typically, however, it's either a Windows graphical/background or console application, which are similar except a console process automatically inherits or creates a console, unless started with the `DETACHED_PROCESS` flag. A console process also implicitly gets duplicates of the parent's standard handles if the parent is also a console process.

Comment: @turmuka, the second part is the entry point. If you're linking with the C runtime, it has different behavior for console apps that use the `[w]main` entry point as opposed to GUI/background apps that use `[w]WinMain`. For example, `_dup2` to FDs 0, 1, and 2 automatically calls `SetStdHandle` in a console app, to keep the standard FDs in sync with the standard handles, but not in a GUI app.